# How to add a new custom link using PHP "if" and "else", in OpenCart 1.5.5.1?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

I'm editing a theme named *AquaCart*, installed in OpenCart 1.5.5.1. I also integrated Twitter [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29)'s fixed top navbar. I already modified the navbar and put the **Login** / **Logout** menu there, and it's doing fine. This project is for my own online store.

I don't have any PHP skills yet, only HTML+CSS. I have managed to put the login/logout button on my new navbar menu by copying codes from my current theme's `header.tpl` file and editing the `header.php` file (from the `catalog\english\common\header.php`).

Now, I am polishing the menu and wanted to add some custom menu/link named **Sign Up!**.
I want this **Sign Up!** menu link to show as **Logout** link when a user is already logged in.

My current edit shows the logged-in user's name in a `<li>`, and a logout menu in a second `<li>`. This is not what I really want. I want to show the **Logout** link in place of the **Sign Up!** link when a user is logged in.

Here is my current `header.tpl` edit:

```
<ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">My Account</a><!--Shall be shown only when user is logged in-->
                <ul>
                    <?php if (!$logged) { ?>
                    <?php echo $text_welcome; ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php echo $text_logged; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Store Front</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog Page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php?route=account/register">Sign Up!</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

My `header.php` from the catalog\language folder of opencart. `text_logged` and `text_welcome` was already edited.

```
<?php
    // header.php from catalog\language\english\common\header.php
    $_['text_home']           = 'Online Shop';
    $_['text_wishlist']       = 'Wish List (%s)';
    $_['text_shopping_cart']  = 'Shopping Cart';
    $_['text_search']         = 'Search';
    $_['text_welcome']        = '<li><a href="%s">Login</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="index.php?route=account/register">Sign Up!</a></li>';
    $_['text_logged']         = '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="%s">Logout</a></li>';
    $_['text_account']        = 'My Account';
    $_['text_checkout']       = 'Checkout';
?>
```

The above code is rendered like so...

..and I wanted to make the **sign Up!** link to become **Logout** when a user is logged in.

[image]

I don't know PHP yet, but I'm struggling on studying the PHP files of OpenCart installation, and I've found this string from my `header.php` file found in `catalog\controller\common`:

```
$this->data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
```

I am thinking of duplicating that, but don't know what to duplicate and modify. And what are other files involved?

---

UPDATE:

I've now added a new Text name "Sign Up" and "Login", so I may not be confused, and I can easily substitute it to my Text Link.

So far.. I've added:  In my `catalog\english\common\header.php`:

```
$_['text_login']  = 'Login';
$_['text_signup']  = 'Sign Up!';
```

And in my `catalog\controller\header.php`.

```
$this->data['text_login'] = $this->language->get('text_login');
$this->data['text_signup'] = $this->language->get('text_signup');
```

### UPDATE 2:

I've re-marked up my Menu, based from shadyxx opinion, I've changed the menu a bit. So for "not Logged-in Users"... This menu should be echoed...

[image]

Marked up like this:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And for LOGGED-IN USERS, this menu should be echoed...

[image]

Marked up like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Account></b></a>
            <ul>
                <li>%s</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>Shopping Cart</a></li>
                <li>Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my `catalog\controller\common\header.php`:

```
$this->data['signup'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_signup'), $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL'));
$this->data['login_register'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_login_register'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL'));
$this->data['logged_in'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged_in'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->data['text_shopping_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_shopping_cart'), $this->data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart'), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
```

In my catalog\language\english\common\header.php

```
$_['text_login_register']
= '<div>
     <ul>
         <li>Login</a></li>
         <li>Register</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>';

$_['text_logged_in']
= '<div>
       <ul>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>
                       <li class="divider"></li>
                       <li><a href="%s">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                       <li><a href="%s">Checkout</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="%s">Logout</a></li>
           </ul>
       </ul>
   </div>';
```

In my header.tpl

```
<?php if (!$logged) { ?>
<?php echo $login_register; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo $logged_in; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

So, what's not working, using the above codes is the checkout menu. The checkout menu is redirecting a user to the Shopping Cart Page.

I've just copy pasted the above codes. I've tried to understand the use of the existing code and by trial and error.

Comment: I've simplified the sample markup for better presentation and explanation. The "Logout" link menu below the Logged in User Name (client one), shall be removed. Because the Logout Link Menu shall be echoed in place of the "Sign Up" Link Menu, when a user is logged in.

Comment: @shadyyx Problem Solved. I think I'm gonna have to learn PHP first, before learning PHYTON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you do not want to have **My Account** link when there is no user logged in...as it would make no sense to be shown for the *visitors* (not-logged-in users).

I would show only the **Sign Up!** link, and after logging in, I would show only the **My Account** menu that would have the desired **Logout** link (so as it is right now).

So keep your current template as is, and using this code block (you have given us):

```php
<?php if (!$logged) { ?>
<?php echo $text_welcome; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo $text_logged; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

We can modify your top navbar slightly... The condition `<?php if (!$logged) { ?>` applies if there is no user logged in, so inside it we will show the **Sign Up!** link, then the `<?php } else { ?>` gets applied if there is a user logged in. Thus we will move the **My Account** menu there. This code is just an example (as you didn't provide us with the navbar source code...):

```php
<ul id="top-navbar>
    <?php if (!$logged) { /* only visitor */?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $signup; ?>"><?php echo $text_signup;?></a></li>
    <?php } else { /* logged in user */?>
    <li><span>My Account</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><span><?php echo $text_logged; ?> <?php echo $logged_username; ?></span></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $logout; ?>><?php echo $text_logout; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

In your controller you would have to push the language strings, URLs and username to the template and in language file you would have to add the text strings needed for your menu (if you hadn't done so far...).

---

**EDIT:**

Your thinking is good, but the approach not. Do not put HTML into language files, nor controllers, unless really necessary or no other way is possible (which may not occure and if yes, something is wrong).

So, put all the HTML into your template file (`header.tpl`) and use PHP variables:

```php
<?php if (!$logged) { ?>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $login; ?>"><?php echo $text_login; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $signup; ?>"><?php echo $text_signup; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $text_account; ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $username;?></a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart;?>"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $logout; ?>"><?php echo $text_logout; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now many of the URLs and texts are already defined thus we need to add only few of them.

Open your language file (`catalog\language\english\common\header.php`) and add/modify these:

```php
$_['text_login'] = 'Log In';
$_['text_signup'] = 'Register';
$_['text_logout'] = 'Log Out';
```

You can remove the previous `text_login_register` and `text_logged_in` variables with its values.

Now open the controller (`catalog\controller\common\header.php`) and find the part that ends with this line:

```php
$this->data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
```

And after it, add these lines:

```php
$this->data['text_login'] = $this->language->get('text_login');
$this->data['text_signup'] = $this->language->get('text_signup');
$this->data['text_logout'] = $this->language->get('text_logout');

$this->data['login'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL');
$this->data['signup'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL');
$this->data['logout'] = $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL');

$this->data['username'] = '';
if($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->data['username'] = $this->customer->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->customer->getLastName();
}
```

Now you should be done.

Comment: Thanks, like I said... Im just editing the Theme, so I am just relocating the menus and is using the current Menu Links. Your suggestion is great, as you've provided the codes too. That's a treat for me.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope this will help You to solve the problem. Should You need further help, it would be better to provide us with the top navbar code You have modified so far... Good luck!

Comment: I've modified a bit, the menu. Based from your opinion. The "My Account" menu shall only be shown to logged-in users. Most the text links are working, except for the checkout menu and shopping cart. Shopping Cart menu is redirected to page not found, while, Checkout Menu is redirecting to Shopping Cart. Logout Menu is working fine. I don't know much, how to modify the header.php file in controller.

Comment: @shadyyyx Perfect! That was exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Exactly the logic what I've thought of. The PHP Variables did exactly what I had in mind. Much thanks! Problem Solved! I don't have the code `$this->data['checkout']...` in my template, so I've added it. That was the reason I can't access the checkout. Oh boy... I need to have some PHP skills... By the way, is it a huge effort If I wanted to redirect a user to the page where he/she logged in? 'Coz right now, after a user is logged in, the page is redirected to My Account page.

Comment: Unless You have *login form* accessible in the sidebar (thus on every page) the user is able to log in only during the checkout or from `account/login` page. Redirecting the user back to login page (`account/login`) when he is already logged in has no sense. I don't think redirecting to My account page is that big deal, anyway You can edit `catalog/controller/account/login.php` - `index()` method and check for the part where method `redirect` is called - You can then change the URL it is redirecting to.